# checking a char **array for values

Tags: c

I got a `char **function` which returns obviously an Array of chars.... the problem is that I don't know how many strings are filled in the array .... `char *data[size_of_data];` has been set at the first, but the function may not need all the array fields....

presume I got `int size_of_data = 100` , but it just got 15 Strings .... if I want to break after the 15th String, which condition do I need in C ... I got the data already in a char ** field and tried sth like....

```
 while(strcmp(data[i],'\0'))
{
    msg_send (session, para[0],data[i]);
    printf("------> %s \n",data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Do you know what C does to sign the end of any-type array?

Comment: tell me I thought NULL or'\0' but I am wrong... I m still struggling with c ... coming from Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to also provide the size of the array as an out parameter. Your function signature would look like this

```
char ** function(size_t * num_strings); //num_strings is an out parameter
```

Then you do something like so

```
size_t nstrings = 0;
char **strings = function(&nstrings);
size_t i = 0;
while (i < nstrings) {
    //do stuff
}
```

There's an advantage to knowing the size, instead of just iterating until you hit a null pointer. Say you prepared an array of 100 `char*`. What if you use them all? There's no null pointer, and you'll have overrun your buffer. Of course, you could add an extra pointer at the end as a  delimiter, but personally I like having the size.

Comment: Out parameters always feel like a hack to me. Even if some standard interfaces use it.

Comment: For stylistic reasons, you could also write the function signature as `void function(char **arr, size_t *num)` . I think this looks a bit nicer, and to my mind the intent is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your char **function you can put a NULL pointer at the end of your array. So in this case put a NULL after 15th string. Then in your while loop check data[i] == NULL, if its that's the end.

Comment: thnks but is there no other way... what I wanted to know is what happens in c at the char *data[15] if I wouldn't put a Null pointer... sth like '\0' or NULL should be automatically set otherwise to which element does the pointer point on the heap at data[15] if not NULL ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to have the function place a null pointer (0) into the data array at the first location that is not used.

This can simply be tested by checking to see if the current pointer is 0:

```
for (i = 0; data[i]; i++) {
    puts(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two common things you can do, either the convention of indicating the *end-of-array* with a nullpointer or return a `struct` that contains an additional `size_t` which holds the number of elements. There is also a variation of the second version using the iterator idiom.

#### end is null:

```
char** fun() {
  /* ... */
  char** array = /*...*/;
  unsigned end = 15;
  array[end] = NULL;
  return array;
}
```

The caller will then stop reading from the result array when it encounters a `NULL`.

#### separate size

```
struct {
  size_t size;
  char** array;
} fun() {
   /* ... */
   char** array = /*...*/;
   unsigned end = 15;
   return {end,array};
}
```

#### iterator idiom (lent from C++)

```
struct {
  char** begin;
  char** end;
} fun() {
   /* ... */
   char** array = /*...*/;
   unsigned end = 15;
   return {array,array+end};
}
```

This has the advantage that is can be used nicely in loops:

```
for (struct {char** begin; char** end;} it = fun(); it.begin != it.end; ++it.begin) {
  printf("%s\n",it.begin);
}
```

And you can also determine the size easily by subtracting `end - begin`.